# In Microchip C18, why does the insertion of a NOP cause much larger code?

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, pic18

I have some code in an ISR. The code is given for completeness, the question is only about the commented-out __asm_ block.

Without the __asm_ block, this is compiled into 82 instructions. With the __asm_ block, the result is 107 instructions long. Why the big difference?

Here's the C code:

```
if (PIR1bits.SSPIF)
{
    spi_rec_buffer.read_cursor = 0;
    spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor = 0;

    LATAbits.LATA4 ^= 1;
//      _asm nop nop _endasm
    LATAbits.LATA4 ^= 1;

    while (!PORTAbits.NOT_SS && spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor < spi_rec_buffer.size)
    {
        spi_rec_buffer.data[spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor] = SSPBUF;
        SSPBUF = spi_out_msg_buffer.data[spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor];
        PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
        spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor++;
        spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor++;
        if (spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor == spi_out_msg_buffer.write_cursor)
            LATAbits.LATA4 = 0;
        LATBbits.LATB1 = 1;
        while (!PORTAbits.NOT_SS && !PIR1bits.SSPIF);
        LATBbits.LATB1 = 0;
    }

    spi_message_locked = true;
    spi_message_received = true;

}
```

Without NOPs:

```
BTFSS     0x9e,0x3,0x0      if (PIR1bits.SSPIF)
BRA       0x2ba
                            {
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_rec_buffer.read_cursor = 0;
CLRF      0x4,0x1
CLRF      0x5,0x1
CLRF      0x6,0x1               spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor = 0;
CLRF      0x7,0x1
BTG       0x89,0x4,0x0          LATAbits.LATA4 ^= 1;
BTG       0x89,0x4,0x0          LATAbits.LATA4 ^= 1;
MOVF      0x80,0x0,0x0          while (!PORTAbits.NOT_SS && spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor < spi_rec_buffer.size)
ANDLW     0x20
BNZ       0x2b0
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x7,0x0,0x1
XORWF     0x3,0x0,0x1
BTFSS     0xe8,0x7,0x0
BRA       0x254
RLCF      0x3,0x0,0x1
BRA       0x25c
MOVF      0x2,0x0,0x1
SUBWF     0x6,0x0,0x1
MOVF      0x3,0x0,0x1
SUBWFB    0x7,0x0,0x1
BC        0x2b0
BRA       0x240
                                {
MOVF      0x0,0x0,0x1               spi_rec_buffer.data[spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor] = SSPBUF;
ADDWF     0x6,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xe9,0x0
MOVF      0x1,0x0,0x1
ADDWFC    0x7,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xea,0x0
MOVFF     0xfc9,0xfef
MOVLB     0xf                       SSPBUF = spi_out_msg_buffer.data[spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor];
MOVF      0x10,0x0,0x1
ADDWF     0x14,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xe9,0x0
MOVF      0x11,0x0,0x1
ADDWFC    0x15,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xea,0x0
MOVF      0xef,0x0,0x0
MOVWF     0xc9,0x0
BCF       0x9e,0x3,0x0              PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;
MOVLB     0xf                       spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor++;
INCF      0x6,0x1,0x1
MOVLW     0x0
ADDWFC    0x7,0x1,0x1
MOVLB     0xf                       spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor++;
INCF      0x14,0x1,0x1
ADDWFC    0x15,0x1,0x1
MOVF      0x16,0x0,0x1              if (spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor == spi_out_msg_buffer.write_cursor)
XORWF     0x14,0x0,0x1
BNZ       0x29e
MOVF      0x17,0x0,0x1
XORWF     0x15,0x0,0x1
BNZ       0x29e
BCF       0x89,0x4,0x0                  LATAbits.LATA4 = 0;
BSF       0x8a,0x1,0x0              LATBbits.LATB1 = 1;
MOVF      0x80,0x0,0x0              while (!PORTAbits.NOT_SS && !PIR1bits.SSPIF);
ANDLW     0x20
BNZ       0x2ac
MOVF      0x9e,0x0,0x0
ANDLW     0x8
BZ        0x2a0
BCF       0x8a,0x1,0x0              LATBbits.LATB1 = 0;
                                }
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_message_locked = true;
MOVLW     0x1
MOVWF     0x18,0x1
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_message_received = true;
MOVWF     0x19,0x1
                            }
MOVLW     0x4            }
SUBWF     0xe1,0x0,0x0
BC        0x2c4
CLRF      0xe1,0x0
MOVF      0xe5,0x1,0x0
MOVWF     0xe1,0x0
MOVF      0xe5,0x1,0x0
MOVFF     0xfe7,0xfd9
MOVF      0xe5,0x1,0x0
MOVFF     0xfe5,0xfea
MOVFF     0xfe5,0xfe9
MOVFF     0xfe5,0xfda
RETFIE    0x1
```

With NOPs:

```
BTFSS     0x9e,0x3,0x0      if (PIR1bits.SSPIF)
BRA       0x30e
                            {
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_rec_buffer.read_cursor = 0;
CLRF      0x4,0x1
CLRF      0x5,0x1
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor = 0;
CLRF      0x6,0x1
CLRF      0x7,0x1
BTG       0x89,0x4,0x0          LATAbits.LATA4 ^= 1;
NOP                             _asm nop nop _endasm
NOP
BTG       0x89,0x4,0x0          LATAbits.LATA4 ^= 1;
MOVF      0x80,0x0,0x0          while (!PORTAbits.NOT_SS && spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor < spi_rec_buffer.size)
ANDLW     0x20
BNZ       0x302
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x7,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
XORWF     0x3,0x0,0x1
BTFSS     0xe8,0x7,0x0
BRA       0x27e
RLCF      0x3,0x0,0x1
BRA       0x28c
MOVF      0x2,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
SUBWF     0x6,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x3,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
SUBWFB    0x7,0x0,0x1
BC        0x302
BRA       0x268
                                {
MOVLB     0xf                       spi_rec_buffer.data[spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor] = SSPBUF;
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x0,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
ADDWF     0x6,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xe9,0x0
MOVLB     0xf
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x1,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
ADDWFC    0x7,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xea,0x0
MOVFF     0xfc9,0xfef
MOVLB     0xf                       SSPBUF = spi_out_msg_buffer.data[spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor];
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x10,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
ADDWF     0x14,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xe9,0x0
MOVLB     0xf
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x11,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
ADDWFC    0x15,0x0,0x1
MOVWF     0xea,0x0
MOVF      0xef,0x0,0x0
MOVWF     0xc9,0x0
BCF       0x9e,0x3,0x0              PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0;                           // Interruptflag löschen...
MOVLB     0xf                       spi_rec_buffer.write_cursor++;
INCF      0x6,0x1,0x1
MOVLW     0x0
ADDWFC    0x7,0x1,0x1
MOVLB     0xf                       spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor++;
INCF      0x14,0x1,0x1
MOVLW     0x0
ADDWFC    0x15,0x1,0x1
MOVLB     0xf                       if (spi_out_msg_buffer.read_cursor == spi_out_msg_buffer.write_cursor)
MOVF      0x16,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
XORWF     0x14,0x0,0x1
BNZ       0x2ea
MOVLB     0xf
MOVF      0x17,0x0,0x1
MOVLB     0xf
XORWF     0x15,0x0,0x1
BNZ       0x2ee
BCF       0x89,0x4,0x0                  LATAbits.LATA4 = 0;
BSF       0x8a,0x1,0x0              LATBbits.LATB1 = 1;
MOVF      0x80,0x0,0x0              while (!PORTAbits.NOT_SS && !PIR1bits.SSPIF);
ANDLW     0x20
BNZ       0x2fe
MOVF      0x9e,0x0,0x0
ANDLW     0x8
BNZ       0x2fe
BRA       0x2f0
BCF       0x8a,0x1,0x0              LATBbits.LATB1 = 0;
                                }
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_message_locked = true;
MOVLW     0x1
MOVWF     0x18,0x1
MOVLB     0xf                   spi_message_received = true;
MOVLW     0x1
MOVWF     0x19,0x1
                            }
MOVLW     0x4            }
SUBWF     0xe1,0x0,0x0
BC        0x318
CLRF      0xe1,0x0
MOVF      0xe5,0x1,0x0
MOVWF     0xe1,0x0
MOVF      0xe5,0x1,0x0
MOVFF     0xfe7,0xfd9
MOVF      0xe5,0x1,0x0
MOVFF     0xfe5,0xfea
MOVFF     0xfe5,0xfe9
MOVFF     0xfe5,0xfda
RETFIE    0x1
```

Here's a screenshot of a partly diff (click to enlarge):
[image: Diff]

Comment: "Why the big difference? " - have you tried comparing the two pieces of code with a diff tool?

Comment: Of course I did. I don't know how to present the result in a readable way here, so I hoped anyone interested would copy and paste it to their favorite diff tool themselves. I could put up a screenshot of a part of it.

Comment: Well, I don't know. ;) I don't know much about assembly and memory layout on this platform. I found http://www.electro-tech-online.com/microcontrollers/38480-mplab-c18-added-nop-loop-decreased-execution-time.html#post304269 which could be related but gives little information anyway.

Comment: Why has this been downvoted? Seems like a good enough question to me.

Comment: Do you use explicit optimisation flags?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So that people don't have to guess, here's a statement from [the Microchip C18 manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/c18_user_guide_51288j.pdf) (emphasis added):

> It is generally recommended to limit the use of inline assembly to a minimum. **Any
>   functions containing inline assembly will not be optimized by the compiler.** To write large
>   fragments of assembly code, use the MPASM assembler and link the modules to the C
>   modules using the MPLINK linker.

I think that this is a common situation with inline asm.  GCC is an exception - it will optimize the inline assembly along with the surrounding C code; in order to do this correctly, GCC's inline assembly is quite complex (you have to let it know which registers and memory are clobbered).

Comment: This is the most complete answer here. Other answers get the issue right (Inline asm causes problems for compilers), but looking at the position of the nop within the code it seems that even assuming the asm clobbered all registers, the succeeding code would be optimisable. So, only a quote from the manual describing how any function with inline asm will not be optimised can truly explain the behaviour.

Comment: I double-checked the compiler flags and found that I was actually compiling with optimization. When I turn optimization off (`-o-`) the listing with and without __asm_ is identical.

Comment: As this is an ISR adding a function call would make things worse, so now I faked the NOP by writing a second time to a volatile register.

Answer (score 3):

#### *Inline asm block == no optimization*

It seems that the compiler emits the MOVLB instructions before any access to *"banked RAM".*

The optimizer takes the extra ones out. (And some other stuff.)

The optimizer doesn't run when you have inline assembly.

So adding that inline block is the same thing as *turning off optimization*.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that it's to do with optimisation.

The compiler sees that you're inserting a chunk of assembly language, it doesn't know what effect it will have, so it just acts more cautiously.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler seems to have a rellatively poor extension to include assembler. Basically it gives no hint at all back to the compiler, which register you are using, perhaps modifying etc. To produce consistent code the assembler that he produces has to be significantly different then. He has to re-initialize all its registers to known values.

Other compilers, e.g gcc, have `asm` extension that let you be more specific on these things. In particular you have effective ways of telling the compiler which memory and registers are affected by your assembler code. For them such a `NOP` instruction would introduce not much more than an "optimization barrier".

Answer (score 0):

As MRAB has mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554608/in-microchip-c18-why-does-the-insertion-of-a-nop-cause-much-larger-code/6554654#6554654), this is likely an optimization issue. Try moving the assembly instructions into their own function.

A function call is probably going to add more overhead than 2 `NOP`s, so you can try messing with the function once you've figured out whether it makes a difference. For instance, try declaring the function `inline`, or write the function as a C callable assembly function (assuming this is possible with your compiler).